# Limit of distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, distribution-theory

I'm trying to solve the following excercise, whitout any luck.

Let  $\eta(x)=\begin{cases} c \exp\left(\dfrac{1}{|x|^2-1}\right), & \text{if} \;|x| \leq 1 \\ 0 & \end{cases}   $  $\qquad \text{for }x\in \mathbb R^d$

$c$ is chosen such that $\int_{R^d}\eta~dx=1$

Set now $\eta_\epsilon(x)=\dfrac{1}{\epsilon^d}\eta\left(\dfrac{|x|}{\epsilon}\right)$ 
(I think it looks strange but there is an actual absoulte value on $x$)

Show that $$ \lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0} \eta_\epsilon=\delta \qquad \text{in } \mathcal D'(R^d) $$

Comment: The absolute value is a common notation for the eucludean norm. So $|x|=|(x_1,\dotsc,x_d)|=\sqrt{x_1^2+\dotso+x_d^2}$.

Comment: Limit in the distribution space means that the integral over $\mathbb R^d$ of $\eta_\epsilon\cdot f$ tends to $f(0)$ for any smooth compactly supported function $f$, right? If the support of $f$ does not include the origin, the integrals will eventually be zero since the $\eta$s will be supported outside the support of $f$. Otherwise, I think you have to write this as integral of $\eta_\epsilon\cdot(f-f(0))$ tends to zero, split the integrals into two pieces, one on a ball around the origin and the other one outside, and try showing both can be made arbitralily small by opportune choice...

Comment: ...of $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

We can write by definition for a test function $\phi$

$$\langle \eta_\epsilon,\phi\rangle = \int_{\Bbb R^d} \frac{c}{\epsilon^d} \exp\left(\dfrac{1}{|x|^2/\epsilon^2-1}\right)\phi(x)dx = \int_{\Bbb R^d}  {c}  \exp\left(\dfrac{1}{|y|^2   -1}\right)\phi(y\epsilon)dy.$$
By dominated  convergence theorem the latter intergral converges to $\phi(0)$ as $\epsilon\to 0$, hence $\eta_\epsilon\to\delta_0$.